# Excepion handling in mvc does not change the url on execution of controller and SEO optimization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, exception

So I have below mechanism to handle exception in my mvc application. Basically, I am trying to handle it on `Application_EndRequest()` in `Global.asax.cs` file.

```
protected void Application_EndRequest()
{
     int status = Convert.ToInt32(Context.Response.StatusCode);
     if (status != 200)
     {
          var controller = "Error";
          var action = "Index";
          Response.Clear();
          var rd = new RouteData();
          //rd.DataTokens["area"] = "AreaName"; // In case controller is in another area
          switch (status)
          {
               case 404:
                        action = "NotFound";
                        break;
               default:
                        action = "UnknownError";
                        break;
           }
           rd.Values["controller"] = controller;
           rd.Values["action"] = action;
           IController c = new ErrorController();
           c.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), rd));
     }
}
```

Everything is working fine and it displays `NotFound` view when status is `404` and `UnknownView` for all the other default `5xx` errors. Now when I see the `url` it does not change:

**Ex:** I try to visit a view say `domainname.com/Gallery/Img` which does not exist and I will be redirected to `NotFound` View but the url remains as it is i.e.`domainname.com/Gallery/Img`. I want this to be changed to like `domainname.com/Error/NotFound`

A image below to show the problem:
[image: Problem Visualized]

Now few doubts too on this:

> - If I change the `url` on redirection to `errorview` will it appear in google search when searched for my website.
> - Which way is better? changing the url? or keeping it as it is?  **the reason being is I do not want neither my `error` urls nor the  non-existing urls which the user searched for, to appear in the google search while users search for my site!**

Any help with little bit of explanations to understand the concept properly on this is highly appreciated!

Comment: It doesn't change the url as you've not applied a 302 redirect, simply cleared the response up to the error `response.clear` in your code then returned the response of the error page.   Personally, I'd keep it this way as there's nothing worse than a 404 page that changes the url so you can't tell what was wrong (might have just been a small typo, and you can no longer simply fix that typo).   No idea about SEO, hence just a comment.

Comment: @freedomn-m Correct me if am worng? So basically because of `Response.clear` the `url` does not get changed here??

Comment: No, because you don't do a redirect, the url does not get changed.   The `response.clear` means you don't get half the original page followed by the error page (depending on where the exception occurred) and you get a nice clean error page.

Comment: That's nice @freedomn-m.. Let me see for 2 days and if no one answers then please post your comments as answer and will accept it and will edit my question too..